# try to create shopping basket with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

```html
<body>
    <img src="2.jpg" id="first">
    <img src="3.jpg" id="second">
    <img src="4.jpg" id="third">

    <div id="basket">

        <p id="fir">number:</p>
        <button id="firstbtn"> left</button>


        <button id="secondbtn">right</button>


    </div>
</body>
```

I want to create a shopping basket for practice. My code does not work correctly. I want to increase or decrease the number of products when a drag & drop happens!

Where is my problem?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1

  $("#first").draggable();

  $("#basket").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight", function() {
        $("#first").css({
          "left": "0px",
          "top": "320px"
        }, $("#fir").css({
          "display": "block"
        }))

        $("#firstbtn").click(function() {
          $("#fir").html("number:" + i--)
        })

        $("#secondbtn").click(function() {
          $("#fir").html("number:" + i++)
        })
      })
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: It's very hard to tell you where the problem is without seeing your html code

Comment: Please create a [mre].

Comment: One issue is that you've put a `css()` call as the second argument of another `css()` call. It will probably actually work without error, but the syntax is incorrect.

Comment: ????? i put as it was saying 3 more to go.

Comment: Another issue is that you've assigned `click` handlers inside the drop event.  This means if you drag more than once, you'll get more than one click handler and `i` will increase exponentially.   Move the click handlers into the doc.ready.  Though it's a little unclear what these are actually *meant* to do.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen i add a html to my code when click the left buttom increased but when click the right first time increased but  after that decreased